# Passing same .env to multiple Docker containers

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I am developing a Spring Boot application that has many services, each one deployed in a Docker Container. I am also using Docker Compose and a common `.env` file that has all the environment variables for all containers. Then I assign to each container the variables that they use. For example:

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
    service1:
      build:
        context: ./
      container_name: service1
      network_mode: "host"
      environment:
        VAR1: ${VAR1}
        VAR2: ${VAR2}
        VAR3: ${VAR3}
        VAR4: ${VAR4}
        VAR5: ${VAR5}
      expose:   
        - 8085
        
        
    service2:
      build:
        context: ./
      container_name: service1
      network_mode: "host"
      environment:
        VAR1: ${VAR1}
        VAR2: ${VAR2}
        VAR3: ${VAR3}
        VAR6: ${VAR6}
        VAR7: ${VAR7}
      expose:   
        - 8086
```

And the `.env` file looks like this:

```
VAR1=a
VAR2=b
VAR3=c
VAR4=d
VAR5=e
```

As you could see, some variables are shared between multiple containers (in this case `VAR1`, `VAR2` and `VAR3`).

It is quite cumbersome to define the environment variables that apply for each container. Because of this, I am wondering if there is any problem if I just add all environment variables to all container using the followg configuration (env_file):

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
    service1:
      build:
        context: ./
      container_name: service1
      network_mode: "host"
      env_file: ./.env
      expose:   
        - 8085
                
    service2:
      build:
        context: ./
      container_name: service1
      network_mode: "host"
      env_file: ./.env
      expose:   
        - 8086
```

The applications will no do anything with the extra environment variables and use only the ones that are defined inside the application.

This approach works well, but I am not sure if this could cause some problems? Security ones, for example

Comment: Having extra environment variables usually isn't a problem; do you run into any specific problems with your latter form?

Comment: Not actually. But I am not sure if there is any problem with the second approach in terms of security or something else

Comment: Compose isn't designed for production, so if this is just in dev then it's fine. (not a criticism if you are btw, I use compose in prod for a PoC I'm working on).